# In Ruby, Copy text from remote host(s) to local host

Tags: ruby, docker, ssh

***Disclaimer*** I am very new to Ruby!

I am currently writing a program (using Ruby) to ssh into a remote host from my local host. The program must then copy the docker processes running and print them to *.txt file in my local host. Please note: I do not need to be within any containers, I simply need to record the process.

How can I copy the docker processes on a remote host to a *.txt file on the local host?

I have got the ssh part down, but due to some constraints cannot publish any of my code.

I appreciate any responses and have a good day everyone!

Comment: What is your actual problem? What are you stuck on? What kind of answer are you hoping to get here?

Comment: @Kenster How can I copy the docker processes on a remote host to a *.txt file on the local host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try saving the output of the `ps` into a text file on that server and then using the [net-scp gem](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-scp) to move the output file to your local host.

```
# download a file from a remote server
Net::SCP.download!("remote.host.com", "username",
  "/remote/path", "/local/path",
  :ssh => { :password => "password" })
```

Comment: I actually thought of something similar when discussing the matter with my peers later yesterday. I will give this a shot and up vote/ mark correct if it works! Thanks for the help

Comment: Fsho! good luck :) The gem is a little outdated though.. but I hope it works!

Comment: Any luck? @CreeFC

Comment: Still having some issues @AlbertHu

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a remote command on ssh and then store output of this command to your txt file.

```
ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'ps -eaf| grep docker' > output.txt
```

I guess this what you need.

Comment: ssh user@x.x.x.x "ps -efC" > note.txt